Guice constructor injection with MapStruct
How to modify this class to use mapstruct, given that I use Guice for the constructor injection? I tried this way, but I get this compile error:  constructor TransactionMapper in class ... cannot be applied to given types
This is the initial mapper that we are supposed to refactor:
public class TransactionMapperImpl implements TransactionMapper{
    protected final CurrencyService currencyService;
    protected final TransferService transferService;
    @Inject
    public TransactionMapperImpl (CurrencyService currencyService,
                                              TransferService transferService) {
        this.currencyService = currencyService;
        this.transferService= transferService;
    }
    @Override
    public TransactionDTO map(TransactionListResponseItemInfo trx) {
        return TransactionDTO .TransactionDTOBuilder.transactionDTO()
                .beneficiaryName(trx.getName())
                .maxAmount(trx.getMaximumAmount())
                .build();
    }

Here is the version with MapStruct that we tried to compile:
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")
public abstract class TransactionMapper {
  TransactionMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(TransactionMapper.class);
  protected final CurrencyService currencyService;
  protected final TransferService transferService;
  @Inject
  public TransactionMapper(CurrencyService currencyService,
                                              TransferService transferService) {
     this.currencyService = currencyService;
    this.transferService= transferService;
  }
  @Mapping(target = "beneficiaryName", source = "beneficiary")
  @Mapping(target = "maxAmount", source = "maximumAmount")
  public abstract TransactionDTO map(TransactionListResponseItemInfo trx);

Any idea on how we can make MapStruct use the constructor injection from Guice?
